# /FIXED\ Android - TextView don't show below another TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, textview, cardview

I've got some TextView in a CardView, but when i try to set my TextView "text_lieu" below the TextView "text_nom", nothing happened they are confused. Can you help me please ? <3

Here my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_nom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:padding="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_heure"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:padding="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_lieu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_nom"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Wrap them in a LinearView with a orientation of vertical.

Comment: I've did that but my TextView "text_heure" go to the midline but i want it at the end of the first line. Like "text_nom" at the start of the first line, "text_heure" at the end of the first line and "text_lieu" at the start of the second and end line.

Comment: look at my answer.... with a linear layout, you put the views where you want them. For example, if you want view 1 to be at the bottom... you would view V2, V3, V1 in that order within the linear layout. again, look at my answer...

Comment: Oh i see, it works nice, thanks for your fast answer. Did you know how i can do to make "Text_lieu" invisible if there is no text inside ? Because when there's no text, the cardview is too big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:layout_below` is only effective in a `RelativeLayout`. 
You can put your views inside a `RelativeLayout` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_nom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_heure"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:padding="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_lieu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_nom"
            android:padding="20dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Edit**:

```
if (myTextView3.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty())
    myTextView3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
else
    myTextView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: It works thank ! I've got a last question, how can i make "Text_lieu" invisible if there is no text because now my cardview is too big when there is no "text_lieu" text

Comment: By code you can do: `text_lieu.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: What need i place in my if() ? It's myTextView3 http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/45/3/1541617842-capture.png

Comment: I guess it's `myTextView3`.

Comment: Yup but i don't know what condition to place for the setinvisibility

Comment: The condition is `myTextView3.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()`, this means that there is no text inside `myTextView3`. See the edit in my answer.

Comment: Sorry i do wrong, i reaccept. Thanks for all you do, the condition works good ! Have a nice day =)

Answer (score 2):

A `CardView` extends a [`FrameLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout) basically. That means that views are placed on top of each other, not in a linear fashion like in a `LinearLayout`. To do this you want to put your `TextViews` in a `LinearLayout` inside the `CardView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
android:layout_margin="10dp">

<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_nom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:padding="20dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_heure"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:padding="20dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_lieu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_nom"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Note the orientation `vertical` in the linear layout.

If you want to keep the FrameLayout style, an item in it has the property `android:layout_gravity` which you can set to `bottom` to place an item in the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the textviews in a `LinearLayout`. You can adjust them they are are, you dont need to do the `layout_below`. `LinearLayout` will take care of that for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
android:layout_margin="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_nom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_lieu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_heure"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```